# codeigniter with ajax on success refresh the listing

Tags: ajax, html, codeigniter, jquery

im using codeigniter with ajax to post form. below is the ajax code im using. code make post successful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#post_submit').click(function() {
  var form_data = {
    csrfsecurity: $("input[name=csrfsecurity]").val(),
    post_text: $('#post_text').val()    
  };

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('/post_status'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    success: function(response){
      $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    }
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
```

but im listing the status posts on same page, so i want once the ajax post success the listing should get refresh without refreshing whole page. i want to refresh the particular listing section and show the last posted stats without refreshing whole page.

Answer (score 1):

Ok once the post is complete your server should return the updated list values by querying the  database table for the values, and in following section of your code you should update your list

```
success: function(response){
  $(".home_user_feeds").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
  $("#div_list").html(response);
}
```

The reason why you need to query the database is that other users might be posting data as well so you want to see every post in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can configure your controller/model to query the latest changes from your database, wrap-it-up using json_encode:

```
   $result = $this->mymodel->getupdates();
   print json_encode(array('success' => TRUE, 'rows' => $result));
```

and then in your script, using the success handler in jquery ajax, loop through the rows to create a dynamic html from the response:

```
   var htm = '';
   for(r in response.rows){
      htm = htm + 'dynamic_html'; //make a construction here
   }

   $("#div_list").append(htm); //if you want to append only latest update
   $("#div_list").html(htm); //if you want to replace your current view
```